# Node JS Interactive Gallery with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropdown, body-parser

Hey Guys I'm working on a small project for a short course I have and it's about making this Gallery with a dropdown list to make a request to the server for the image that you selected in the dropdown list and display it on the page, and it also requires a login/register form to access the gallery. Right now I'm working on the dropdown list and I'm not entirely sure how to make it work.

This is what I have so far:

NodeJS:

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require("path");     
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("client-sessions");
const randomStr = require("randomstring");

var strRandom = randomStr.generate();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.engine(".hbs", exphbs({ 
    defaultLayout: "main",
    extname: ".hbs" }));
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");    

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));  

app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render('index');
});

app.post("/submitPicture", function(req, res){
    var moreDogs = req.body.dogs;

    res.redirect('index');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server ready correctly");
});
```

JavaScript HBS:

```
<form action="/submitPicture" method="POST">
      <select name="dogs" id="dogs">
            <option> </option>
            <option value="corgi">Corgi</option>
            <option value="samoya">Samoya</option>
            <option value="huski">Siberian Husky</option>
            <option value="beagle">Beagle</option>
            <option value="golden">Golden Retriever</option>
      </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <article>
            <aside><p id="string">Samoyed</p></aside>
            <img src="img/samoyed-dog.jpg" id="selected">
  </article>
```

The images I keep them as local files in this path: \public\img\dog.jpg
Also, this is the layout for the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vAvY.jpg

I might have an idea how to use the body-parser npm to extract the json object from the post form, but I not so sure how to code it for a dropdown list

I just starting in nodejs so any advice would be greatly appreciate it!